# Using psexec on a bat file that contains psservice

Tags: windows, batch-file, service, cmd, sysinternals

I have a bat file that tries to stop a service on a remote machine, the file contains the following

```
psservice \\remoteServerName -u domainName\userName -p password stop serviceName
```

where userName is a name of a user with Admin privileges on the remote machine.

If I run the last line using cmd then the requested service does stop.

I, however, run the bat file using psexec, since it contains more operation than just stopping the service. This is where my problem occurs:

If I run

```
psexec -u domainName\userName -p passsword batFilePath
```

the cmd window seems to get stuck.

But if I run

```
 psexec batFilePath
```

then the psservice executes correctly.

My problem is that I need the user "domainName\userName" to be able to run the other commands in the bat file.

What can I do ? Why does the cmd got stuck when I gave psexec the parameters of the userName and password ?

Comment: If psservice hasn't been run on the remote machine before, it will be waiting for you to accept the EULA.  Try `psservice /accepteula ...`